# Having trouble installing Bradcom STA driver

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

I just installed Ubuntu and love it so much, its so fast now. But I have a problem connecting to the internet.

I checked and saw I have to install the driver **Broadcom STA** wireless driver but every time I do try to install it it says:

```
Sorry, installation of this driver failed. Please have a look at the log files for
details: /var/log/jockey.log
```

I went to the terminal and copy and pasted the log file name. and when I did it, it said I have no permission to access this file. I checked on the forums that I have to be on a wired connection. So I plugged my laptop into my router and I got internet then tried to install the driver again. And it was loading then when it got to the end the same message popped up.

Also I have one of those little USB router things you plug into the computer and it gives you internet I have been using that but its to slow. So I want to use the one in my computer but cant.

Also I tried the command:

```
sudo modprobe wl
```

and when i type that command in it says:

```
FATAL: Module wl not found
```

Also I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 1):

My friend, I had the same problem and I solved like this:

- First, uninstall the bcmwl-kernel-source

  ```
   sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
  ```
- Install the firmware-b43-installer

  ```
   sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
  ```
- And the b43-fwcutter

  ```
  sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter
  ```
- Restart your computer

I hope that works for you =)

[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

You need root permission to unlock that log file
Open terminal and type

```
  sudo gnome-control-center
```

You will be able to install drivers after that